# Create large string upto 4mb from Arraylist of String: gives outofmemoryerror for StringBuilder.append

Tags: java, string, arraylist, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I want to create large string from `Arraylist` of `Strings`.

The `arraylist` contains parts of a big text file.

original size of file is upto 5MB.

I have used following way to do it.

```
private void createFilefromChunks(ArrayList<String> stringval2) {
    try {
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

        StringBuilder completeFile = new StringBuilder(150);
        String val = null;    

        for (Iterator<String> iterator = stringval2.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            val = (String) iterator.next();
            completeFile.append(val);
        }
        System.out.println(completeFile.toString());
    }
    catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Above method works fine for small files upto 1MB,

but if my file size is increased to 4MB, it will give me an `OutofmemoryException`

Following is my Logcat details:

```
12-26 14:43:17.862: E/dalvikvm-heap(718): Out of memory on a 2100160-byte allocation.
12-26 14:43:17.862: I/dalvikvm(718): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-26 14:43:17.862: I/dalvikvm(718):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a14568 self=0x2a00b9e0
12-26 14:43:17.862: I/dalvikvm(718):   | sysTid=718 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073870640
12-26 14:43:17.871: I/dalvikvm(718):   | schedstat=( 16034835833 4219745479 1751 ) utm=1509 stm=94 core=0
12-26 14:43:17.871: I/dalvikvm(718):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~94)
12-26 14:43:17.871: I/dalvikvm(718):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
12-26 14:43:17.871: I/dalvikvm(718):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
12-26 14:43:17.871: I/dalvikvm(718):   at com.example.splitbychapter.MainActivity.createFilefromChunks(MainActivity.java:160)
12-26 14:43:17.871: I/dalvikvm(718):   at com.example.splitbychapter.MainActivity.readAsperChapter(MainActivity.java:120)
12-26 14:43:17.871: I/dalvikvm(718):   at com.example.splitbychapter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
12-26 14:43:17.881: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-26 14:43:17.881: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-26 14:43:17.881: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-26 14:43:17.881: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-26 14:43:17.881: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-26 14:43:17.881: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-26 14:43:17.890: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 14:43:17.890: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 14:43:17.890: I/dalvikvm(718):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-26 14:43:17.890: I/dalvikvm(718):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 14:43:17.890: I/dalvikvm(718):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 14:43:17.890: I/dalvikvm(718):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-26 14:43:17.890: I/dalvikvm(718):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-26 14:43:17.901: I/dalvikvm(718):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 14:43:17.901: W/System.err(718): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-26 14:43:17.920: W/System.err(718):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
12-26 14:43:17.920: W/System.err(718):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
12-26 14:43:17.930: W/System.err(718):  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
12-26 14:43:17.930: W/System.err(718):  at com.example.splitbychapter.MainActivity.createFilefromChunks(MainActivity.java:160)
12-26 14:43:17.940: W/System.err(718):  at com.example.splitbychapter.MainActivity.readAsperChapter(MainActivity.java:120)
12-26 14:43:17.940: W/System.err(718):  at com.example.splitbychapter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
12-26 14:43:17.940: W/System.err(718):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-26 14:43:17.940: W/System.err(718):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-26 14:43:17.940: W/System.err(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-26 14:43:17.952: W/System.err(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-26 14:43:17.952: W/System.err(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-26 14:43:17.952: W/System.err(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-26 14:43:17.952: W/System.err(718):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 14:43:17.961: W/System.err(718):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 14:43:17.961: W/System.err(718):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-26 14:43:17.971: W/System.err(718):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 14:43:17.980: W/System.err(718):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 14:43:17.980: W/System.err(718):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-26 14:43:17.980: W/System.err(718):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-26 14:43:17.991: W/System.err(718):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It grows my heap size upto 13MB as well and throws `outOfMemoryError`.

It throws error for `StringBuilder` at this line `completeFile.append(val);`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have a random `ByteArrayBuffer` in there for no obvious reason? And is there any reason you're iterating manually rather than using an enhanced for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to create larger strings if you know how big you need them to be to start with - you can create the `StringBuilder` with the exact capacity required, so it will never need to expand. It's during expansion that the memory requirements are largest. So:

```
int size = 0;
for (String value : stringval2) {
    size += value.length();
}
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(size);
for (String value : stringval2) {
    builder.append(value);
}
String x = builder.toString();
```

Now the final conversion to `String` may still cause a problem - but if it does, there's not a lot you'll be able to do, to be honest.

Also note that text in Java takes two bytes per character, so if this is being read from an ASCII file which is 5MB in size, you'll end up with 10MB required for the string.

Do you *have* to put all of this into a single string? Given that you're running on mobile devices (by the looks of it) you should really be trying to think of ways to use less memory if you can.

Comment: i need to put it all in one string, because i want to use this string for Pattern.split

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to append all elements of your list? Can you process them one by one? In your example you can simply print them one by one instead of concatenating.

I'm afraid, if you are so low on memory, even Jon's idea of precalculating StringBuilder size may not be sufficient - it will save you from up to double memory consumption during concatenation, but you will still have to call StringBuilder.toString after that, which will allocate another length of concatenated string.

Another idea (I suppose you are doing something with files) is to use a ByteArrayOutputStream (also - with precalculated size - File.length is a good guess) and them call its writeTo(OutputStream) method for writing a result into output stream. This method does not make a copy of internal buffer.